# How to wait for the tx confirmation in zkSync?

Tags: typescript, solidity, hardhat, ether

How to wait for the tx confirmation in zkSync?

I'm writing a small contract ro swap 2 tokens using zkSync and Hardhat.
Here's how I deploy test tokens:

```
await tokenA.approve(router.address, await tokenA.totalSupply())
await tokenB.approve(router.address, await tokenB.totalSupply())
//TODO: await here
await router.addLiquidity(tokenA.address,  tokenB.address, 1000000
```

I heard that zkSync is forming a block of tx's and confirm them in eth only after block fully set.
Is it true?
How should I properly wait for end of this block confirmation?

I'm using `await setTimeout(30000);` but it does not look like a proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to await the confirmations as well

```
let tx = await tokenA.approve(router.address, await tokenA.totalSupply())
await tx.wait(1);

tx = await tokenB.approve(router.address, await tokenB.totalSupply())
await tx.wait(1)

tx = await router.addLiquidity(tokenA.address,  tokenB.address, 1000000)
await tx.wait(1)
```

To explain more, the first call creates a transaction on the block chain, the second call awaits for the confirmations to occur